# Python and Opencv: I can't connect to camera ip Ezviz C6CN

Tags: python-3.x

I use Ezviz studio to change my ip address (When i connect to ezviz studio, i must to import verification code). I change Ip address of camera to 192.168.100.6. But i can't connect to my camera with python

import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
cap.open("http://192.168.100.6:8000/1")
while(True):

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imshow('Stream IP camera opencv',frame)

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:SZGBZT@192.168.1.2/h264_stream')
```

where admin is always `admin` and the password `SZGBZT` is the verification code on your camera

Comment: Please explain to OP why this solution works in comparison to his code. It looks like we just wants a single frame.